# How to test the "onChange" function who will change the value of state with the hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, enzyme

How to test the "onChange" function
who will change the value of state with the hooks
directly using anzyme in react js.
How to test the "onChange" function
who will change the value of state with the hooks
directly using anzyme in react js.

```js
function BrockerConfig(props) {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Switch
      onChange={setDisabled}
      checkedChildren={<IntlMessages id="settings.Switch.Activation" />}
      unCheckedChildren={<IntlMessages id="settings.Switch.Deactivation" />}
    />
  );
}

it("onChange state of Disabled", () => {
  const BrockerConfigComponent = () => shallow(<BrockerConfigForm />).dive();
  const TotalSwitchs = BrockerConfigComponent().find(Switch);
  expect(TotalSwitchs.length).toBe(1);

  TotalSwitchs.simulate("change", "true");
  expect(TotalSwitchs.state("disabled")).toEqual("true");
});
```

Comment: Hi, I have seen few solutions: mock `useState` from `React`, Check the component that use `disable`.

Comment: I did not find the solution to test the function "onChange" and "setState" at the same time

Answer (score 1):

First thing: having `BrockerConfigComponent` as a function means that each call to it returns new and completely independent instance. You will not be able to mutate it and check results. Let's having it as a variable:

```
const BrockerConfigComponent = shallow(<BrockerConfigForm />).dive();
```

Wrappers in Enzyme(everything returned by `find()`, `filter()`) [are read-only](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2139). You need to re-fetch it after simulating action:

```
  TotalSwitchs.simulate("change", "true");
  expect(BrockerConfigComponent.find(Switch).state("disabled")).toEqual("true");
```

Probably you better not put `.find()` to interm variables at all to avoid such cases in the future.

Now as for `state`. It's always bad move to set or assert on state since it is implementation details. And here it will not even work at all because for `shallow()` your nested components(like `Switch` here) are not rendered/initialized.

So what could you do? Validate against rendering results. Interact through calling props("simulating" events call props as well). Let's assume your `disabled` variables is passed as prop to the same `Switch`.

```
BrockerConfigComponent.find(Switch).simulate("change");
expect(BrockerConfigComponent.find(Switch).props().ifIDisabledProp).toBe(true);
```

Comment: but still there is another problem at the state reading level                                   
                                                                                                                                
     ● Test Brocker Configuration › onChange state of Disabled

    ShallowWrapper::state() can only be called on the root
   
 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `disabled` of type `string` supplied to `Input`, expected `boolean`. in Input

Comment: yes, right. Since it's `shallow()` `Switch` is not rendered. So does not have state. I've updated and extended answer.

Comment: Can you help me to solve the problem "ShallowWrapper :: state () can only be called on the root"

Comment: use `mount()` instead of `shallow()`.

Comment: The use of "mount ()" causes several errors for that I used "shallow ()"

Comment: if your real element is same way easy(`Switch` is only child) you can try `wrapper.dive().state()`. otherwise you _technically_ cannot access state for nested element while `shallow()`.